# Long running Dispatch function making react-native app slow in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm using redux toolkit for state maintenance.

I've complex dispatch function.
Ex:

**fibCalculations.actions.ts**

```
  const fib = (num) : number => {
        var num1=0;
        var num2=1;
        var sum;
        var i=0;
        for (i = 0; i < num; i++) 
        {
            sum=num1+num2;
            num1=num2;
            num2=sum;
        }
        return num2;
    }
       

const getFibResult = (input: number) => (dispatch: AppDispatch, getState: () => RootState): void => {
    const result = fib(input);
    dispatch({
      type: ActionTypes.UPDATE_RESULT,
      payload: result
    });
  }
};
```

**fibCalculations.reducer.ts**

```
const _updateResult = (state, action) => {
     state.result = action.payload
}

const FibSlice = createSlice({
  name: "FibReducer",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
   .addCase(ActionTypes.UPDATE_RESULT.toString(), _updateResult)
   .addDefaultCase(state => state);
  }
});
```

**ResultScreen.tsx**

```
const ResultScreen: FunctionComponent<IResultScreenProps> = props => {
   
 const navigateSecondScreen  = () => {
     dispatch(getFibResult(100))
     navigation.navigate("SecondScreen");
   
 }

   return 
    <View>
     <Button onPress= {navigateSecondScreen}></Button>
   </View>

}
```

In above ex. on button press the dispatch function calls getFibResult func, which takes few seconds to execute, then app navigates to Second screen, which is result in janky behaviour.
Is there a way to execute `getFibResult`, without blocking the navigation?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers